# start emulator based on newly built android source code

Tags: android, build, emulation, jit, dalvik

I have downloaded android source code and made some changes to 
    `dalvik/vm/interp/Jit.cpp`. I have built the source code using

```
           $source build/envsetup.h 
           $lunch full-eng 
           $make -j4
```

The build was successful. Now when I start the emulator by

```
           $out/host/linux-x86/bin/android list targets 
           $out/host/linux-x86/bin/android create avd -n virtual - t target_api 
           $out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator -avd virtual
```

the emulator starts but when I check the libdvm.so file properties in emulator using

```
           $adb shell 
           #cd system/lib 
           #ls -l lidvm.so
```

the file creation date is 2011-12-14. I thought that the emulator is 
starting on standard android 4.0.3 api (where libdvm.so might have 
    been created on that date). Now I want to make the emulator start with my 
    newly built code (that is I want to see the changes I made in dalvik 
    source code in the emulator). How could I possibly achieve this? 
    Thanks.